# Android: App crashes since changing the id-tags of some views (using Eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Since some week's i am working on an app consisting of 3 activitys. 2 of them uses fragments. There are 31 layout-files (XML) in my project total. All was working fine ...... to yesterday.....

By creating the layouts for the fragment i used the auto-generated id's from eclipse (textView1, textView2 and so on). Yesterday I wanted some id's to rename. But something was going wrong. (i don't check the preview by dialog, so there was changed in other fragments and codeparts too. I try to remove the wrong changes,but it seems i forgot something, or just dont know about something)

All is fine when i toogle the fragment, but if i want to change something (e.g setText() on a TextView) the app crashes. It seems it couldnt find the View ("null object reference") but formally the app has found the View by id.

Here is the Error Log: ( i marked the critical part with a comment )

```
05-11 08:37:22.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6875): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-11 08:37:22.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6875): Process: com.nobody.allstuffapp, PID: 6875
05-11 08:37:22.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6875): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
05-11 08:37:22.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6875):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4020)
05-11 08:37:22.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6875):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
05-11 08:37:22.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6875):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
05-11 08:37:22.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6875):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
05-11 08:37:22.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6875):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-11 08:37:22.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6875):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-11 08:37:22.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6875):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
05-11 08:37:22.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6875):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-11 08:37:22.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6875):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-11 08:37:22.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6875):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
05-11 08:37:22.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6875):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
05-11 08:37:22.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6875): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-11 08:37:22.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6875):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-11 08:37:22.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6875):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-11 08:37:22.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6875):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
05-11 08:37:22.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6875):     ... 10 more
05-11 08:37:22.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6875): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
05-11 08:37:22.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6875):     at com.nobody.allstuffapp.LoginActivity.AGB1Show(LoginActivity.java:338)
05-11 08:37:22.753: E/AndroidRuntime(6875):     ... 13 more
```

And here is the source of the activity (blanked out some parts):

```
package com.nobody.allstuffapp;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import org.json.JSONArray;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.nobody.allstuffapp.db.AppStatus;
import com.nobody.allstuffapp.internet.RequestGetTask;

public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public int shownfragment;
    private Context mContext;
    Bundle extras = new Bundle(); 
    private String ex_userName;
    private String ex_userEmail;
    private String ex_userPW;
    private boolean ex_userKeepLogged;

    private static String nameOfUserSetting = "LastUser.log";
    private static String nameOfAGBFile     = "Usertherms.txt";
    private static String nameOfDRightsFile = "Datarights.txt";
    private static String nameOfHelpFile    = "Help.txt";

    private File appFilesPath;
    private File UserLogFile = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.BaseColor));

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.login_contentframe, new LogonFragment()).commit();
            shownfragment = 0;
        }

        mContext = this;

        // get extra strings
        extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        ex_userName = extras.getString("userName");
        ex_userEmail = extras.getString("userEmail");
        ex_userPW = extras.getString("userPW");
        ex_userKeepLogged = Boolean.valueOf((extras.getString("userKeepLogged")));

        // get files-dir
        appFilesPath = mContext.getFilesDir();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

        // Fragment Logon Creator
        public  class LogonFragment extends Fragment {

            public LogonFragment() { }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
                return rootView;
            }
        }

        // Fragment Registrationsformular Creator
        public static class RegisterFragment extends Fragment {

            public RegisterFragment() { }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register, container, false);
                return rootView;
            }
        }

        // Fragment Nutzerbestimmungen Createtor
        public static class AGB1Fragment extends Fragment {

            public AGB1Fragment() { }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_agb1, container, false);
                return rootView;
            }
        }

        // Fragment Datenverwendungsrichtlinien Createtor
        public static class AGB2Fragment extends Fragment {

            public AGB2Fragment() { }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_agb2,container, false);
                return rootView;
            }
        }

        // Logon Screen einblenden
        public void HomeShow(View view){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.login_contentframe, new LogonFragment())
            .commit();
            this.setTitle(R.string.title_activity_login);
            shownfragment = 0;
        }

        // Registrationsformular einblenden
        public void RegisterMe(View view) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.login_contentframe, new RegisterFragment())
            .commit();
            this.setTitle(R.string.str_register_title);
            shownfragment = 1;
        }

        private void hideKeyboard() {   
            // Check if no view has focus:
            View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
            if (view != null) {
                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            }
        }

        // Nutzerbestimmungen einblenden
        public void AGB1Show(View view) {
            AGB1Fragment agb1Fragment = new AGB1Fragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.login_contentframe, agb1Fragment)
            .commit();
            this.setTitle(R.string.str_login_usertherms);


// ================= this will cause a crash (log shown below) ====================
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.lay_agb1).findViewById(R.id.tv_agb1_agbcontent)).setText("Hello World!!!");

// ========= same happens without searching for layout id =====================
// = no problems till yesterday. Only the R.id.tv_agb1_agbcontent chanched =
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_agb1_agbcontent)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_agb1_agbcontent)).setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.txt_agb1)));


        }

        // Datenverwendungsrichtlinien einblenden
        public void AGB2Show(View view) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.login_contentframe, new AGB2Fragment())
            .commit();
            this.setTitle(R.string.str_login_datatherms);
            shownfragment = 1;  
        }


}
```

The Activity layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.nobody.allstuffapp.LoginActivity" >

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/mytoolbar" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/login_contentframe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset" >
    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

And here is the fragment_agb1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:id="@+id/lay_agb1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_agb1_agbcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:text="@string/txt_agb1"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay_agb1_button_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_agb1_button_back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/str_cont_register"
                android:onClick="HomeShow"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/bz_main_nobanner" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_agb1_buttoncaption_back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="@string/str_login_back"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_agb1_copyright"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/str_login_copyright"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope somebody of you can help me. I couldn't find the problem yet. 
Sorry for my bad english.

thx.

**EDIT:** ===================================================================

I Think i found the problem, but how to solve ???:

for explaining: if there are tow layout files with a TextView called "TextView1", so both will have the same Resource-ID in R-File. if i change the name in one of the Layouts, so it will change the name in the other too. If i use the Preview of the update Reference Dialog-Box and only select the layout i want to change and the java-file wich uses the reference without selecting the R file to update, then i produce the error-reason. But if i select the r file to update, then the Object of the other layout looses his Reference the same way. Right?

**Now the question:** how can i rename a textview (by id) and Eclipse add's a new Resource-int not rename the existing, wich is existing now for a other Object??

Comment: have You cleaned Your project?

Comment: yes, more than one times....

Comment: check if the R. which is imported, is YOUR R., for example R.com.example.yourpackage instead of R.android.xxx ......

Comment: it seems to be the R. i could reproduce the problem, but how can i rename  a view in a layout and change the R without changing the view in another layout with the same name in R. It should have two different resource int's at least, but it isn't build by eclipse.... Understand me? will make a new post here where i try to show the problem....

Comment: The best solution is to import the project in Android Studio, and rename the IDs there. Android Studio is much better at refactoring, while Eclipse is a broken mess in comparison.

Comment: ok. I will do so. but i never worked with android studio before....

Answer (score 0):

Second layout that you have posted is "fragment_agb1.xml" but in actvity_login.xml you have included layout "mytoolbar". This could be the problem.

Can you verify the name?

Comment: mytoolbar is an include. Its similar to a second action-bar. fragment_agb1.xml is loaded by activity.java to login_contentframe (scrollbox).

Answer (score 0):

> ((TextView)
>   findViewById(R.id.lay_agb1).findViewById(R.id.tv_agb1_agbcontent)).setText("Hello World!!!");

Try to replace this line with:

```
((TextView)agb1Fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.tv_agb1_agbcontent)).setText("Hello World!!!");
```

---

**Edit.**
Try to create `public` reference of your `TextView` in `AGB1Fragment` class:

```
public TextView tv_content;
onCreateView(...) {
...
tv_content = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv_agb1_agbcontent);
...
}
```

And then use it:

```
agb1Fragment.tv_content.setText("Wow");
```

Comment: your edit: the same result. null-object. It seem's to be the R-File. See my Edit in main-post.

Comment: @Justl24 open your layout in 'Graphical Layout' find the View - context menu - Edit ID

Comment: sorry, context goes the same way like editing in properties-list, so there is the same problem...